# php mysql if sum not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
trans_id  trans_product  trans_user  trans_date  trans_date2  trans_description  trans_inventory
     13         6              1     1278604284   1278547200                     -1000
      9         5              1     1278601462   1278547200    New Arrival        200
     11         7              1     1278601743   1278547200                        50
     12         6              1     1278601756   1278547200                      5000
```

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *, SUM(IF(trans_inventory>0,trans_inventory,0)) as pos "
                  +"FROM site_trans GROUP BY trans_product") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $amt_p = $row['pos'];
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT *, SUM(IF(trans_inventory<0,trans_inventory,0)) as neg "
                      + "FROM site_trans GROUP BY trans_product") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        $amt_n = $row2['neg'];
    }

    echo $amt_p; //working
    echo $amt_n; // not working
}
```

First sql query is working ($amt_p) however second one is for negative isn't working($amt_n) any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: I think your while loops are wrong, do you really want the second sql query inside the first while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `$amt_n` for each product.  I'd suggest combining the queries into something like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *, "
                  + "SUM(IF(trans_inventory>0,trans_inventory,0)) as pos, "
                  + "SUM(IF(trans_inventory<0,trans_inventory,0)) as neg "
                  + "FROM site_trans GROUP BY trans_product") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $amt_p = $row['pos'];
    $amt_n = $row['neg'];

    echo $amt_p;
    echo $amt_n;
}
```

Comment: i cannot upvote the answer because not enough reputation. 

Anyhow, good job Mark. Its working perfectly.

Comment: @DeveloperChris, what? the intent from the original query seemed to be "positive" and "negative" values grouped by trans_product, that's what this produces. (not to mention the OP is saying this is yielding correct behavior)

Comment: @DeveloperChris: furthermore, see the [OP's other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205513/mysql-fetch-sum-php) which confirms this is correct.

Comment: yeah my bad, The OP actually changed his question partway through, the original actually summed the positive and negative values for ALL records, while your answer displays a different result for each grouping. When I responded I was referring to his original source code he provided. sorry for the inference, your answer works fine for his reworked question. (which still doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score 1):

Add `$amt_n = 0`  to initialise it
change `$amt_n = $row2['neg'];` to `$amt_n += $row2['neg'];`

the problem is you are zeroing the value when iterating over it

You need to do this for both pos and neg

DC

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working, but it looks to me that you just want all the positive and negative trans_inventory rows.  How about you add "where trans_inventory>0" to your first query and get rid of that conditional IF hoohah?

```
SELECT *, SUM(trans_inventory) as pos 
FROM site_trans
WHERE trans_inventory>0
GROUP BY trans_product
```

And what exactly do you mean by "not working"?  What values are you getting, and what were you expecting?

Comment: i getting 0 and its should be -1000 on product_id 6